# Swing: can't center a vbox inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout, vbox, hbox

I have this code that creates a simply JPanel with text

```
User profile panel
username: a user
email: email@gmail.com
Button1 Button2
```

Each row - is a `HorizontalBox` and all rows come into a `VerticalBox`. I try to center the result `VerticalBox`, but it doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProfile extends JPanel  {
    {
        setup();
    }
    public void setup() {
        Box vBoxUserData = Box.createVerticalBox();

        Box hBoxUsername = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        hBoxUsername.add(new JLabel("username: "));
        hBoxUsername.add(new JLabel("a user"));
        vBoxUserData.add(hBoxUsername);

        Box hBoxEmail = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        hBoxEmail.add(new JLabel("email: "));
        hBoxEmail.add(new JLabel("email@gmail.com"));
        vBoxUserData.add(hBoxEmail);

        Box hBoxButtons = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        hBoxButtons.add(new JButton("Button1"));
        hBoxButtons.add(new JButton("Button2"));

        Box vBoxContent = Box.createVerticalBox();
        vBoxContent.add(new JLabel("User profile panel"));
        vBoxContent.add(hBoxUsername);
        vBoxContent.add(hBoxEmail);
        vBoxContent.add(hBoxButtons);

        vBoxContent.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        vBoxContent.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        hBoxUsername.setBackground(Color.RED);

        add(vBoxContent);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestProfile());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

while I need it to look like this:

[image]

Also I'm confused why

```
        hBoxUsername.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

didn't paint it in red?

Comment: (1-) You were given the answer in your question yesterday. All components need the same alignmentX. You were also given an example of how to do vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

A Box layout just stacks its children in its natural direction.  If you want to stretch out the space before those children, add [glue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Box.html#createGlue()) to the box before and after the children that you want centered:

```
Box vBoxContent = Box.createVerticalBox();
vBoxContent.add(new JLabel("User profile panel"));
vBoxContent.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
vBoxContent.add(hBoxUsername);
vBoxContent.add(hBoxEmail);
vBoxContent.add(hBoxButtons);
vBoxContent.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

But this alone isn’t enough.  Your TestProfile class extends JPanel but never sets the layout.  The default layout is a FlowLayout, which won’t attempt to make its child fill its space, so you won’t ever see the effects of adding the glue components.

This can be fixed by using a layout that forces the (sole) child component to fill the entire space of the JPanel, such as [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html):

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(vBoxContent);
```

Finally, JLabels are transparent except for their content.  If you want to fill a JLabel with a color, [make it opaque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)):

```
hBoxUsername.setBackground(Color.RED);
hBoxUsername.setOpaque(true);
```